# Azure AKS Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage

Tags: azure-aks

All my pods got into a evicted state and when I look in to the describe of the fives nodes all of them says: Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage

how can I solve this?

Comment: related : https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/884